# object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

hmm I seem to have a problem, on my main window I am trying to do this:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StudentIDProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("StudentID", typeof(String), typeof(LoginWindow), new PropertyMetadata(OnStudentIDChanged));

    public string StudentID
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(StudentIDProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StudentIDProperty, value); }
    }

    static void OnStudentIDChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        (d as LoginWindow).OnStudentIDChanged(e); // 
    }
```

On my other window I have this:

```
MainWindow.StudentID = (String)((Button)sender).Tag;
```

But I get the error:

```
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'WpfApplication4.MainWindow.StudentID.get'
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this? It works for my user controls but not other windows?

My main window is actually named MainWindow so I may have had this confused.

Comment: Think about this: *which* `MainWindow` do you want to change the `StudentID` for?

Comment: @JonSkeet. The *main* one of course. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to set StudentID on an instance of your MainWindow class. Try

```
((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).StudentID = (String)((Button)sender).Tag;
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `MainWindow` is the name of your class, not an instance of MainWindow. You need something like:

```
MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
mw.StudentID = (String)((Button)sender).Tag;
```

Comment: Except that just creating a new MainWindow instance is almost certainly *not* the right thing to do. It's far more likely that the OP wants to get a reference to an *existing* MainWindow.

Comment: I have another issue to battle with aswell related to this (OnStudentIDChanged) I think its more my fault that I named the main window MainWindow.

Comment: Absolutely. I was trying to point the OP to the fact that they are pointing to the *class* MainWindow, and it was probably a typo (possibly they meant: mainWindow instead of MainWindow, or MyApplication.MainWindow), etc.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to update a `TextBox` in the `MainWindow` from a `UserControl` and get the error

```
Error 1: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 

'WpfApplication1.MainWindow.textBox1'
```

I resolved this error by writing the following:

```
//MainWindow.textBox1.Text = ""; //Error 1

((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).textBox1.Text = "";//This is OK!
```

This was suggested by Rytis I